# strapi connection to postgreSQL on render, Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN dpg-cjk5hqdk5scs73a7f9b0-a

Tags: deployment, strapi

I deploy strapi on the render platform. strapi builds correctly, but I get this error when connecting to the postgreSQL database on render:

```
Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN dpg-cjk5hqdk5scs73a7f9b0-a
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:108:26) {
errno: -3001,
code: ‘EAI_AGAIN’,
syscall: ‘getaddrinfo’,
hostname: ‘dpg-cjk5hqdk5scs73a7f9b0-a’
}
```

[here is my code of database.js file in cand config folder:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObLZN.png)

[here is my code of .env file:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgSCW.png)

help me solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

I also use render, I noticed you have
`host: env('DATABASE_HOST', 'your database host url'),`

For me it is `host: env('DATABASE_HOST', 'localhost'),` and it's working perfectly.